# Vectorizing list

Tags: python, text, replace

need help guys. Need to vectorize list, 
that is, replace each element of the sublist with a certain calculated number. Formula for each element of sublist https://i.stack.imgur.com/73xj9.png
The list has the following structure: `list = [[document0],[document1],[document2],[document3].......]`
Each document consists of terms, for example `document1 = ['i','love','you']`

I wrote my function for calculation, but it does not work correctly :(

```
def tfc(slova):
    import math as m
    meshokslov1=[{}for i in range(len(slova))]
    meshokslov2=[{}for i in range(len(slova))]
    SummaKvadratov=0
    for i in range(len(slova)):
        for j in range(len(slova[i])):
            n=0
            for q in slova:
                if q.count(slova[i][j])!=0:
                    n+=1
                    if slova[i][j] in meshokslov1:
                        continue
                    else:
                        meshokslov1[i][slova[i][j]]=slova[i].count(slova[i][j])*m.log10(len(slova)/n)
                        SummaKvadratov+=(slova[i].count(slova[i][j])*m.log10(len(slova)/n))**2
    for i in range(len(slova)):
        for j in range(len(slova[i])):
            if slova[i][j] in meshokslov2:
                continue
            else:
                meshokslov2[i][slova[i][j]]=meshokslov1[i][slova[i][j]]/(SummaKvadratov**0.5)
    return meshokslov2
```

Comment: You could please provide an example with sample input and expected output?

Comment: @VasilisG. For example list=[['I','help'],['will','you']] out list = [[0.707,0.707],[0.707,0.707]] https://radikal.ru/lfp/c.radikal.ru/c38/1804/2d/b8570fca9427.png/htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, following a top-down design for your problem:

```
import math

def frequency(term, document):
    return document.count(term) / len(document)

def totalNumOfDocuments(inList):
    return len(inList)

def numOfDocumentsForTerm(inList, term):
    return len([doc for doc in inList if term in doc])

def TFCWeighting(inList):

    tfc = []

    N = totalNumOfDocuments(inList)

    for document in inList:

        temp = []
        for term in document:

            #numerator
            freq = frequency(term, document)
            n = numOfDocumentsForTerm(inList, term)
            logarithm = math.log(N/n)
            numerator = freq * logarithm

            #denominator
            summation = sum([(frequency(t, document) * math.log(N / numOfDocumentsForTerm(inList, term))) ** 2 for t in document])
            denominator = math.sqrt(summation)

            temp.append(round(numerator / denominator,3))

        tfc.append(temp)

    return tfc

l1=[['can','help','you'],['thank','you'],['help','help','help','help','help','help']]
l2=[['I','help'],['will','you']]

print(TFCWeighting(l1))
print(TFCWeighting(l2))
```

Output:

```
[[0.577, 0.577, 0.577], [0.707, 0.707], [0.408, 0.408, 0.408, 0.408, 0.408, 0.408]]
[[0.707, 0.707], [0.707, 0.707]]
```

Comment: You're right, delete it. The line `terms = getAllTerms(inList)` and then the loop `for t in terms` when calculating the result does the same job.

Comment: Wait, I also need to take the length of one particular document and sum over this length, rather than the length of all terms from all documents. For example l=[['I','help','qwer'],['will','you']] M for first document=3, for second=2

Comment: Can you post the expected output of the above?

Comment: list=[['can','help','you'],['thank','you'],['help','help','help','help','help','help']]   OUT = [[0.577 0.577 0.577][0.707 0.707][0.408 0.408 0.408 0.408 0.408 0.408]]

Comment: @ Vasilis G. thank you. Can you somehow optimize the functions for calculation? for the 25,000 documents the computational process is infinite